# Is there any standard to define the accuracy of RTD transmitters

Tags: rtd

I wonder if there is any standard which defines how is the accuracy of RTD, pT100 in particular, tranmistter defined and with which confidence level.

Comment: Don't you calibrate them to your situation?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

There is for the sensors, but for transmitters, I don't think so.

Manufacturers will specify something like a reference accuracy (immediately after calibration after a long warm-up at a reference ambient temperature and other conditions) and then some numbers to calculate the maximum added error due to ambient changes, resistance of the wires and so on. If there are standards, I think they are more honored in the breach than the observance, partly because it would be difficult to come up with one set of conditions that would be equally appropriate for, say, HVAC transmitters vs. process transmitters in a chemical plant.

Comment: And what would be the confidence level to use when processing statistics? As you can probably imagine, I am currently designing one transmitter. For example, Fluke uses a confidence level of 99% (+-2.6 sigma) when giving their measurement uncertainty and they say that it depends on the internal standards. Apparently, higher confidence, bigger uncertainty and vice versa ...